# Unable to print 1st element of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I created this c++ program to create a linked list, but I can't print the 1st element of the list.
please help

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    void Insert(int x);
    void Print();
};
Node* head;

void Node::Insert(int x){
    Node* temp=new Node();
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}

void Node::Print(){
    Node* temp=head;
    cout<<"List is "<<endl;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        cout<<temp->data<<"  ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    head=NULL;
    Node q;
    cout<<"Enter number of elements"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int x;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"ENter numbeR"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        q.Insert(x);
        q.Print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

except for the 1st element all elements are printed. I can't get my mistake.

Comment: May I suggest a slight redesign? You have a *list* and each list have *nodes*. So make a `List` class which contains a list of `Node` objects. The `List` class have a function to add nodes, and a function to print the nodes. The `Node` class only have the value and the link to the next node in the list. Should hopefully make things a little bit simpler, as well as make more sense (calling a `Print` function on a single *node* to print the whole list?)

Answer (score 1):

In the Print function, change `temp->next` to `temp`

Here is the updated code with few modifications i did in output presentation format:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    void Insert(int x);
    void Print();
};
Node* head;

void Node::Insert(int x){
    Node* temp=new Node();
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}

void Node::Print(){
    Node* temp=head;
    cout<<"List is "<<endl;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout<<temp->data<<"  ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    head=NULL;
    Node q;
    cout<<"Enter number of elements: ";
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int x;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Input node element: ";
        cin>>x;
        q.Insert(x);
        q.Print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in:

```
while(temp->next!=NULL){
```

when printing. When the list has only one element, the `next` property of that element will be `NULL`. However, due to this constraint, the program does not enter the while loop, and as a result, does not print it. You can correct this by replacing it with:

```
while(temp!=NULL){
```

Then, every non-null element will be printed, i.e., all elements in the list.